# jQuery highlight table row but excluding some rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, highlight, tablerow

I have the following code:

```
$('table tr:not(:first-child)').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered_error');
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

This works great - however, is there is way in which I can **not** highlight certain table rows, for example, rows 11 and 21 or if a table row has a particular `name` or `class`?

EDIT:  Correct code as follows:

```
$('table tr:not(:first-child,[name=header])').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered_error');
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Comment: $('table tr:not(:eq(10),:eq(20))')... because eq works for 0 based index

Comment: `:not` can can be applied to classes as well `:not(.class)` or `:not([name=somerandomnamelol])`

Comment: @Spokey - would this be correct? '$('table tr:not(:first-child),:not([name=header])').mouseover(function() {'

Comment: `$('table tr:not(:first-child, [name=header])')` should do the trick or try to chain them `$('table tr:not(:first-child):not([name=header])')`

Comment: @Spokey - pop it down in the answers and I'll mark as answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can add `classes` or attribute filters to `:not`

```
$('table tr:not(:first-child, [name=header], #id, .class)')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something along these lines for certain row numbers;

```
$('table tr:not(:first-child)').mouseover(function() {
    var hovered = $(this);
    if (hovered.index() != 11 && hovered.index() != 21) {
        hovered.removeClass('hovered_error');
        hovered.addClass('hovered');
    }
}).mouseout(function() {
    hovered.removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Check against the `index()` of the element. You may need to adjust the index +1 or 2 if you want to skip the first row.

Comment: I should have mentioned - I have some table rows that show and hide - and whilst the above works - the show hide seems to affect it.

Comment: Do you mean that as some rows might be hidden, you only want the visible rows 11 or 21 to not be affected, rather than rows 11 or 21 of the table regardless of their visibility...if that made sense?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to add Hover CSS behavior to your table Rows then you can do it with CSS only

```
table tr {
        background-color: azure;
    }
    table tr:hover {
        background-color: beige;
    }
```